# PhantomCSS undefined object in test.success

Tags: javascript, casperjs, phantomcss

I'm writing a test script with PhantomCSS but I'm running into an error. I've already run my script one time and I created the baseline screenshots. Now, when I try to run through it again, it creates the .diff.png images, but then throws the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'test.success')
/path/to/phantomcss.js:426
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'test.success')
#    type: error
#    file: visual.js
#    subject: false
#    error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'test.success')"
#    stack: in anonymous() in /path/to/phantomcss.js:426
FAIL 1 test executed in 4.035s, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

I commented out most of my phantomcss.init() code, but this is what I have left:

```
var phantomcss = require('/path/to/phantomcss.js');

phantomcss.init({
    failedComparisonRoot: './diffs'
});

casper.start(url);

casper.viewport(1024, 768);

casper.then(function() {
    casper.wait(2500, function() {
        phantomcss.screenshot('#app-bar', 'App_bar_initial');
        phantomcss.screenshot('.selected', 'Selected_Menu_Initial');

    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    phantomcss.compareAll();
})

casper.then(function() {
    casper.test.done();
})

casper.run(function() {
    phantom.exit(phantomcss.getExitStatus());
});
```

EDIT: Line 426 from [phantomcss.js](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS/blob/master/phantomcss.js#L426) is:

```
function waitForTests(tests){
casper.then(function(){
    casper.waitFor(function(){
        return tests.length === tests.reduce(function(count, test){
            if (test.success || test.fail || test.error) {
                return count + 1;
            } else {
                return count;
            }
        }, 0);
.....
```

Comment: And what line is 426?

Comment: Added link to the github and code for PhantomCSS.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. If you have installed it with NPM you have to specify the `libraryRoot`

```
var phantomcss = require('../node_modules/phantomcss/phantomcss.js');

phantomcss.init({
  libraryRoot: 'node_modules/phantomcss',
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having. The demo they have in their repo would look like:

```libraryRoot: fs.absolute( fs.workingDirectory + '/node_modules/phantomcss' )```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found that phantomCss would raise this exception if your `screenshots` directory was missing.

This can be specified as follows:

```
phantomcss.init({
    screenshotRoot: './spec/phantomcss/screenshots',
    failedComparisonsRoot: './spec/phantomcss/failures',
    comparisonResultRoot: './spec/phantomcss/results'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was generated because of `phantomcss.turnOffAnimations()`. I removed it.